# How to implement onBackPressed() from Viewpager subFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I am trying implement ***onBackPressed()*** from ViewPager subFragment. I has some issue. I did listener and implement for  both. But it works only for Fragment B. But When I delete implementing from Fragment B, onBackPressed() worked for Fragment A. What I am doing wrong? Any help apraciete!


***Structure***
[image: Structure]

I did listener

```
public interface OnBackPressedListener {
public void onBackPressed();
```

}

In Main activity use this Listener

```
public void setfragmentclick(OnBackPressedListener ob){
    onBackPressedListener = ob;
}

@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        onBackPressedListener.onBackPressed();

    }
```

In Fragment A implement OnBackPressedListener interface

```
MainActivity mainActivity = new MainActivity();
mainActivity.setfragmentclick(this);

....

@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (getChildFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
            getChildFragmentManager().popBackStack();
        }
    }
```

In Fragment B also implement OnBackPressedListener interface

```
 MainActivity mainActivity = new MainActivity();
    mainActivity.setfragmentclick(this);
    ....

     @Override
            public void onBackPressed() {
                if (getChildFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
                    getChildFragmentManager().popBackStack();
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found another way implementing onBack from ViewPager sub Fragment. If you have sub fragment in ViewPager the best way is using  ***KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK***, in ***onResume*** of parent fragment that has child fragments use this:

```
 @Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    getView().setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    getView().requestFocus();
    getView().setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP && keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
                if (getChildFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) 
                    getChildFragmentManager().popBackStack();

                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```